# How can I change the way my cup looks (from top view)?

Tags: transforms

I think I've rotated a face of the cup at the beginning and now it looks a bit off. Is there an easy/ beginner friendly way to look like a 'perfect' circle when in top view ?

Here is my blender file.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any easy trick, what you could do is create a circle to have a reference, give your cup and coffee a *Lattice* modifier with the same lattice object, and bend the lattice until you get a round object?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the tip! i'll try it soon

Comment: +1 for the Keith Haring _Ta-Dah!_

Comment: thanks, I knew it would bring me luck